# Sprinkler project exposed clogged supply line

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

I just had some sprinklers installed and they were tied directly into the supply line from the street before it gets to my house. During this installation, the guy said the metal pipes from the street are filled with rust/sediment and he couldn't get his finger into the 1" pipe. This is probably causing us lower that normal water pressure.

I want to get these metal pipes replaced with something plastic, but I don't know if this is worth doing if the lines are clogged before my water meter. If they are clogged before my meter, does the city have to fix that? What's the best order of operations to tackle this problem?

Comment: It sounds like the guy was hooking up the sprinkler pipes before your water meter.  Most cities will take a dim view of this.  It will depend on your city, but quite a few cheap out and say the homeowner is paying for everything from the street to the house, they only pay for the pipe running down the street.

Comment: Where is your water meter? at the curb, or at your house, or somewhere else?

Comment: The water meter is at the street several yards away from my house. The sprinkler was hooked up near my house where the supply line enters the house at the crawlspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know your pipes are clogged and need to be replaced up to the meter so think about doing that. When your pipe is disconnected from the meter, turn on the meter valve to flush out the meter and you can then determine if the city pipes are clogged too. The city should have to fix anything before the meter.

Answer (score 0):

Where I live the supplier has a valve at their main line, the meter is inside the house, and the line between the two is the homeowner's responsibility.

Replacing it is costly.  It's usually about 6 feet underground, it runs under walks, sidewalks, mature shrubs etc and everything has to be dug out.  The further your house from the road the more it costs.  They do a pretty good job at selling insurance for this work using scare tactics about failures of this line ... but in your case that wouldn't apply since it hasn't failed.